# Creating a function to assume an AWS STS role in PowerShell $PROFILE

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, assume-role

I have AWS credentials defined in my `.aws/credentials`  like follows:

```
[profile source]
aws_access_key_id=...
aws_secret_access_key=...

[profile target]
role_arn = arn:aws:iam::123412341234:role/rolename
mfa_serial = arn:aws:iam::123412341234:mfa/mylogin
source_profile = source

...
```

and I would like to define functions in my `$PROFILE` to [assume roles](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/APIReference/API_AssumeRole.html) using [AWS Tools for PowerShell](https://aws.amazon.com/powershell/) in the said accounts because of MFA and credential lifetime of 1 hours.

The function looks like

```
function Use-SomeAWS {
   Clear-AWSCredential
   $Response=(Use-STSRole arn:aws:iam::123412341234:role/rolename -ProfileName target -RoleSessionName "my email").Credentials
   $Creds=(New-AWSCredentials -AccessKey $Response.AccessKeyId -SecretKey $Response.SecretAccessKey -SessionToken $Response.SessionToken)
   Set-AWSCredential -Credential $Creds
}
```

Copying & pasting the lines within the function work just fine, but sourcing the profile (`. $PROFILE`) and running the function (`Use-SomeAWS`) asks for the MFA code and seems to do its job, however, the credentials do not get correctly set for the session.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: With some further testing, this *does* work if I add `-StoreAs someprofilename` to the Set-AWSCredential *and* after that do `Set-AWSCredential -ProfileName someprofilename` but that **kind of** defeats the purpose.

Comment: You need to be an admin to change roles.  So is script being run as Admin.  Make sure you start powershell by right click shortcut and select Run As Admin.

Comment: @jdweng I'm assuming a [AWS STS Role](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/APIReference/API_AssumeRole.html) - not doing any Windows stuff. Also, as I said, it works perfectly outside a function in powershell.

Comment: I think it is using OAUTH2,  It is part of windows Authentication.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?force_isolation=true&view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio.  What account are you using?  Probably running inside a powershell you are using different credentials.  what do you mean exactly by running successfully outside of Powershell?  What app are you using to make connection?

Comment: No it's not using OAUTH - It's using the native AWS authentication via [AWS Tools for PowerShell](https://aws.amazon.com/powershell/)

Comment: See following : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/userguide/shared-credentials-in-aws-powershell.html?force_isolation=true

Comment: It might be a scoping problem. Did you try it without the call operator (`&`, in your last line)? It is redundant anyway...

Comment: @stackprotector  I think it _is_ a scoping problem, but somehow else.  - I did try and din't help, but removed nevertheless.

Comment: The [Installing the AWS Tools for PowerShell on Windows](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/userguide/pstools-getting-set-up-windows.html) states: "*Although PowerShell 3.0 and later releases typically load modules into your PowerShell session the first time you run a cmdlet in the module, the AWSPowerShell.NetCore module is too large to support this functionality. You must instead explicitly load the AWSPowerShell.NetCore Core module into your PowerShell session by running the following command.*". In other words, did you try `Import-Module AWSPowerShell.NetCore` first?

Comment: @IRon how would that be even remotely relevant? The cmdlets work just fine except that the temporary AWS credentials with `Set-AWSCredential` without `-StoreAs` somehow don't get set outside that particular function scope...

Answer (score 1):

Did you try the -Scope for Set-AWSCredential  ? like this :

```
Set-AWSCredential -Credential $Creds -Scope global
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/reference/items/Set-AWSCredential.html